# How to overlay a custom drawing over a SurfaceView being used as camera preview?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-vectordrawable, android-overlay

***What I want:***

I want to make a `Camera` Activity (i.e. an Activity which shows the Camera Preview) in which a square shape (*it's actually a bit complicated shape but I am saying square for simplicity*) is overlay-ed on the camera preview, so that the user knows where to position the camera such that a particular square shaped real object is positioned inside that square shape overlayed on the camera preview.

Just like there is a face shape in the camera preview in the following image, so that the user can put their face there.

[image]

***My Solution:***

I thought of having a `FrameLayout` and then having `SurfaceView` for the camera preview and a `VectorDrawable` for the shape to be overlayed, as `FrameLayout` would Z-order its children such that `VectorDrawable` will end up being overlayed on `SurfaceView`.

***Problems with it:***

I need my app to be compatible with API 11 and above. So I'd have to use `VectorDrawableCompat`. To use `VectorDrawableCompat`, we need to set an AAPT flag. **[- source](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#9513)**

The problem is that everywhere on the web, the way to set this flag is for Android Studio. (like the method described [here](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#9028)) A few lines are to be added to the project's build.gradle file.

I couldn't find out how to set this flag in Eclipse. I kept searching, and ended up installing the Eclipse Buildship plugin to use Gradle in Eclipse. I followed [this guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html). When I added the Gradle nature to my Android project, I did get a `build.gradle` file. I pasted the code to enable that AAPT flag in it **but it did not help my problem at all.**

**SO NOW I AM LOOKING FOR AN ALTERNATE METHOD TO ACHIEVE MY TASK. PLEASE TELL ME HOW CAN I DO IT, WITHOUT USING `VectorDrawableCompat`?**

Comment: Why don't you use a png file instead of VectorDrawable?

Comment: Because that would be problem for different screen sizes? @nshmura

Comment: Yes, but I think the problem is little. I posted a answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that VectorDrawable is better than png file. 
But I think png is acceptable, because ImageView with dp size will automatically scale the image.

This is example:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/face_shape"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: db size? what's db?

Comment: Won't the image get pixelated with scaled?

Comment: Yes, the image will get pixelated. But If you make png at the appropriate size, I think that it inconspicuous. (Of course it depends on the project requirement..)